# C# MVC: Receive a https post , write cookies and forward to a http endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, response.redirect

I'm trying to set up a https endpoint to receive a POST request , set cookies and forward it to a HTTP endpoint using MVC framework in .NET.

```c#
public class MyController : Controller
{
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
      [AllowAnonymous]
      public ActionResult HttpsPostMessageProcessor()
      {
         //Process the Post Message. write cookies
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("cookieName", "cookieVal");  
        // Forward to http endpoint
        Redirect("http://myhttpendpoint.com");
    }
}
```

when i hit https://myhttpendpoint.com/MyController/HttpsPostMessageProcessor with a post request, i can see that the request is reaching the Redirect call but the browser redirects to https://myhttpendpoint.com/  instead of http endpoint.

I read somewhere that HTTPS posts cannot be redirected to HTTP. 
Can someone explain why? 
Also, is there a workaround?

I don't want the entire site to be https. I want to redirect to http as soon as I process the HTTPS Post message.

PS: I tried using:

```c#
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
```

and

```c#
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ruUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

but that gives me the error,  "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to write a view with a javascript that redirects to the non-ssl url.

`window.top.location = 'http://myhttpendpoint.com';`

if you send a request with ssl, the browser intends to be on ssl. unless you have a client-side action or script that redirects to non-ssl.